# Write shell script for logging in servers and run command after logging in

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting, for

I have wrote a shell script for logging into servers and run few commands to start and stop processes running on it, So I tried below code, but it is showing error, please help me with the script.

```
for i in 'cat /tmp/hb`     //server name would be saved in /tmp/hb
ssh $i
j=hostname 

If $i -ne $j
then
echo "server not logged in"

else echo "Server logged in"
if
$i == $j
sudo /opt/OV/bin/opcagt -status |grep -i ”message agent are not buffering" 

elif
sudo /opt/OV/bin/opcagt -stop
sudo /opt/OV/bin/opcagt -start
sudo /opt/OV/bin/opcagt -stop
sudo /opt/OV/bin/opcagt -status |grep -i ”message agent are not buffering

elif
sudo /opt/OV/bin/opcagt -kill
sudo /opt/OV/bin/opcagt -start
sudo /opt/OV/bin/opcagt -status |grep -i ”message agent are not buffering 

fi
```

Above script gives error :

```
./heart: syntax error at line 2: `ssh' unexpected
```

Comment: You start the `cat /tmp/hb` with a single quote, not a back tick

Comment: Run your code through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) first.  Correct the errors that it finds (which will be numerous) and then update your question.

Comment: Unfortunately the code makes so little sense that I would be surprised if anyone was able to correct the errors with a sufficient probability of the result matching what you think you intend. Describing what it's supposed to do would be one good starting point. [Learning a little](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=learn+bash+scripting) about the scripting language you're trying to use would be sensible, too.

Comment: Yes , I  am trying to fix errors using shellcheck.net.. I didn't know about this site before, it's helpful to me ... as I can check for errors in my script before execution.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that the block that is to be looped through by a `for` needs to have a `do` and `done` block around it:

```
for f in `cat file`
do
  ...
done
```

Your second problem is that the remainder of the loop body (the `if` statements will not be executed inside the `ssh` session on the target host(s). You'll have to somehow push the `if` statements to the target host and execute a script there.

Comment: Thanks a lot... it cleared the idea to alot. I'll come up with the script , with above mentioned points in my mind